# How to test build.sbt code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've got a moderately simple but slightly tricky sbt setup code I want write a few tests for. I would, however, like it to stay in `build.sbt`.

For the time being I've moved it to an object (in `project/`), referenced it in the `build.sbt` as well as in the tests in `project/src/test/scala`.

But is it possible for code in `build.sbt` to be tested?

Comment: You could look into [testing-sbt-plugins](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) which could give you some idea about scripted test framework, which maybe you could use to test your build.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the advice](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#when-to-use-scala-files) in the SBT docs:

> The recommended approach is to define most configuration in .sbt files, using .scala files for task implementations or to share values, such as keys, across .sbt files.

So since this sounds like testable code, and not static configuration, your best bet is to leave it in a Scala file.

I'm sure there's a way to manually evaluate the SBT DSL if you really, really want to, but you'll probably have to dig deep into the docs or the SBT source. I can't help you there, though.